# Prediction with different lags of independent variables

Tags: forecasting, predictor, lags

I am wondering if it is suitable to make 1-step ahead forecast with independent variables of different lags？

Suppose that in practice, one wants to forecast the 1-step head (i.e. 1 month) value of targeted variable, and some relevant independent variables are incorporated. For example, on the last day of 2010:M3 (i.e. March 31, 2010), you want to forecast the stock price of next month (i.e. 2010:M4), then a regression model including predictors with 1 month lagged is naturally considered.

However, you may encounter such a problem, i.e., at the calendar time of March 31, 2010, the most of data of independent variables (X1, X2, X3, X4) is released, but a small part of data of other independent variables (X5, X6)are not available. Then in order to make full use of the data information of independent variables, can we include the predictors with mixed lags, i.e., conduct 1 month lag for X1, X2, X3, X4, and conduct more than 1 month lags (i.e. 2 or 3 lag) for X5 and X6 .The predictive regression is written as:
Y_t+1= a + b1 * X1_t + b2 * X2_t+ b3 * X3_t +b4 * X4_t + b5 * X5_t-1 +b6 * X6_t-2

Thus, my main question is whether this kind of *hybrid-step forecast* is suitable and acceptable for forecasting work? (I have not found any literature discussing this question)

Comment: This does not seem to be problematic in general.

Comment: It is so nice of you, Richard. I am very appreciate you solving my questions so many times.

Comment: To the best of my understanding, the time inconsistency in data availability of predictors are not unusual in practical, but I hardly find related discussion in literature.

Comment: Some things can be fairly obvious yet hard to locate in the literature. But that does not mean they do not exist. That is my impression.

Comment: ok, Thank you so much for conveying me this viewpoint.